# ImproperlyConfigured: Django 1.5 is not supported

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

I'm using the python django framework for a web app on an Ubuntu Virtual Machine. I have run the app before on another virtual machine and it worked perfectly. I think everything is inatalled ok as I can runserver amd collectstatic without any issues.

However, upon pages load I'm give the traceback;

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 243, in __call__
    signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 58, in reset_queries
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 105, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d is not supported." % DjangoVersion[:2])
ImproperlyConfigured: Django 1.5 is not supported.
[11/Sep/2014 08:56:51] "GET /input_parameters HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: What libs do you have installed? If you use [`pip`](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), then provide output of `pip freeze`. Probably, you are using version of lib `sql_server`, that is not supporting django 1.5

Comment: using postgres 9.1 which i belive is ok

Comment: I mean all packages in your python distribution.